# What are the trailing number of the zeroes in the given integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial, decimal-expansion

> **Problem Statement:-** The number of zeroes at the end of the integer
>   $$100!-101!+\ldots-109!+110!$$

I am having a bit of a trouble in thinking how do I proceed. A little push in the right direction would be appreciated.

And if you are posting a full solution do use the **spoiler tag**, as sometimes I cant stop myself from seeing the whole solution and lose the chance of thinking through it by myself with a push in the right direction from you guys.

Also, I dont know whether I am using the right tag feel free to correct it if its wrong.

Comment: The question in the header doesn't match the question in the post.  Do you want the number of zeroes in the integer or just the number at the end?  (the former is a lot harder).

Comment: All numbers have all the factors $\{1\cdots 100\}$ so you can start counting number of times factors of 2s and 5s occur there.

Comment: Assuming you want the number at the end, Hint:  this is the same as asking for the greatest power of $10$ which divides the number.  There are plenty of factors of $2$, so the limiting condition is the factor of $5$.

Comment: Note:  the alternating sum isn't a serious problem....factor out as big a common factor as you can!

Comment: HINT: Factor out $100!$ and calculate the trailing zeros and find the trailing zeroes of the rest of the expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it is easiest to factor the expression as

> $100!(1-101+101\cdot 102-\cdots +101\cdot 102\cdots 110)$.

Then, it is a standard exercise to compute the number of trailing zeros in

> $100!$

The remainder can be computed modulo $10$, $100$, etc, to see how many trailing zeros it has.  For instance, modulo $10$, we are looking at whether

> $0!-1!+2!-3!+4!-5!+6!-7!+8!-9!+10!\stackrel{?}{\equiv} 0\pmod{10}$

to see if this term contributes any trailing zeros.  Since every term with both a factor of $2$ and $5$ is zero modulo $10$, we get that this simplifies to

> $0!-1!+2!-3!+4!\equiv 1-1+2-6+24\equiv 20\equiv 0\pmod{10}$

Now, computing this modulo $100$, we consider

> $0!-1!+2!-3!+4!-5!+6!-7!+8!-9!+10!\stackrel{?}{\equiv} 0\pmod{100}$

A short calculation shows that this simplifies to

> $1-1+2-6+24-20+20-40+20-80+0\equiv 20\not\equiv 0\pmod{100}$

Therefore, the number of trailing zeros is

> The number of trailing zeros of $100!$ plus $1$ since the last nonzero digits >! of $100!$ and $(1-101+101\cdot 102-\cdots +101\cdot 102\cdots 110)$ are 
>  not $5$s (so no additional zeros can be created in the product).

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I did it... I feel foolish now

Comment: @vrugtehagel It's the same basic idea as your approach, I just distilled out the two parts to make the calculations less of a headache.

Comment: thanks for that edit I had already recounted the trailing zeroes in wolfram alpha 8 times and was doubting my ability to count till 10.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - Though can you explain to me roughly how does the modulo function work because I have never read any book on number theory and rely solely on my concepts of binomial theorem for these problem.

Comment: The modulo function is the remainder when divided by $n$.  For example, $24\pmod{10}$ is $4$ because the remainder of $24$ when divided by $10$ is $4$.  If something has zero remainder when divided by $10$, it's a multiple of $10$, and, therefore, has at least one trailing zero.

Comment: A quibble:  The number of trailing $0$'s in a product of two numbers is *at least* the sum of the number of trailing $0$'s in the two numbers individually; it's sometimes *more*, e.g., $20\cdot50=1000$.  You need to mention that the last nonzero digit in $100!$ is not a $5$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good point.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

> $100!$ has 24 trailing zeroes for the number of factors $5$ in $100!$ is $24$, and there are more factors $2$ than $5$.

Then,

> $101!$ also has $24$ trailing zeroes, and so do $102!,103!,104!$, but $105!,106!,107!,108!,109!$ have an extra factor $5$ and thus end in $25$ zeroes. $110!$ ends in $26$ zeroes.

With this,

> We know that $-105!+106!-107!+108!-109!+110!$ ends in at least $25$ zeroes.

So

> if $100!-101!+102!-103!+104!$ ends in just $24$ zeroes, we know that their sum does. But does it end in more than $24$ zeroes?

We now can

> look at the digit before all the zeroes start (the 25th digit from the right). Let's name that digit $d$ for $100!$. Now what is that digit for the other four factorials?

It is

> Since going from $100!$ to $101!$ is only a factor $101$, we can find that digit easily looking $\mod 10$. We see $101d\equiv d\mod 10$ for $101!$, and $102\cdot 101\cdot d\equiv 2d\mod 10$ for $102!$, etcetera; Now we can find the alternating sum,

To arrive at

> $d-d+2d-6d+4d=0$. Thus, the $25th$ digit from the right is also a $0$. We do the same, but look at the last two digits before the trailing zeroes. Let's call those two digits $d_1$ for $100!$

now,

> we need to look $\mod 100$, and obtain the sum $d_1-d_1+2d_1-6d_2+24d_1=20d_1$. Now we need to know, does $20d_1$ end in two zeroes?

Well,

> for $20d_1$ to end in two zeroes, $d_1$ needs to be a multiple of $5$.

But

> every factor $5$ is in the trailing zeroes, and as such, $d_1$ cannot be a multiple of $5$.

Therefore,

> the 26th digit from the right of $100!-101!+102!-103!+104!$ is not $0$, Now what is the 26th digit from the right of $-105!+106!-107!+108!-109!+110!$?

We can use

> the same method; looking $\mod 10$, setting the 26th digit from the right of $105!$ to $d_2$, and noting that $-d_2+6d_2-2d_2+6d_2-4d_2+0d_2=5d_2$. Does $5d_2$ end in a $0$?

Because

> the last nonzero digit of any factorial greater than $1!$ is even, since there are not enough factors $5$ to cancel out all the factors $2$. Thus, the last non-zero digit of $105!$ must be even; thus, $5d_2$ ends in a $0$.

We conclude the final answer

> the number of trailing zeroes must be $25$, since $100!-101!+102!-103!+104!$ has $25$ trailing zeroes and $-105!+106!-107!+108!-109!+110!$ has at least $26$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of zero digits at the end of $n!$ can be found by looking at the factors, and decomposing them into $2$ and $5$ factors. You need one $2$ and one $5$ to produce a trailing zero.

How to combine this with that alternating sum, I have no idea yet.

> BTW: I explained it to my friend Ruby and she tells me the sum is
>  $157393819470814604687108965690332604480484877$\
>  $508029687469884051113407737751285106008107839$\
>  $400103709226880772747397138959112221377791569$\
>  $61431310006359162880000000000000000000000000$

Answer (score 0):

$100!$ has $[\frac{100}{5}]+[\frac{100}{5^2}]=24$ trailing $0$'s.
Now,
$100!-101!+\cdots -109!+110!$
$=m\cdot 100!$ for some positive integer $m$ such that

$m\equiv 0!-1!+2!-3!+\cdots +10!$ (mod $100$)

$\equiv -\{(3!-2!)+(5!-4!)+\cdots +(9!-8!)\}+10!$ (mod $100$)

$\equiv -(2\cdot 2!+4\cdot 4!+\cdots +8\cdot 8!)+10!$ (mod $100$)

$\equiv -(4+96+20+60)$ (mod $100$)

$\equiv -180$ (mod $100$)

$\equiv 20$ (mod $100$)

Thus, we get one more 0 from the factor $m$.
Therefore, required number of trailing $0$'s is $25$.